Discounting equity calculated by the $4/2$ rule
Example: I have $J\spadesuit$ and $A\spadesuit$. Community cards are $5\diamondsuit$, $4\spadesuit$, and $10\spadesuit$. I have 9 outs for a flush and, based on the $4/2$ rule, I have:
$$
4\times9=36\%\text{ equity.}
$$
However, if my opponent has pocket $5$s (none of them spades), then they already have a set of $5$s and also have a chance to get four of a kind or a full house. So, all of the online equity calculators show my equity as $25\%$, i.e., way below the $36\%$ calculated using the $4/2$ rule.
As far as I can tell, there is no simple formula to calculate the $25\%$ equity, and the online calculators use simulations to arrive at this $25\%$ number.
Question:
Is there a shortcut calculation to discount the equity from the 4/2 rule if the opponent has a chance to get a better hand on the turn and/or river?
Based on a suggestion - adding links to definitions for equity and 4/2 rule

There appears to be a lot of very specific jargon here...what's "equity" in this context?  What is the $4/2$ rule?  Perhaps some people here will be familiar with all the jargon, but if you want to attract a wider audience, you might want to define your terms.

As a general rule:  Simulation is by far the most standard way to handle questions like this.  The problems are extremely detail-specific and, while we can usually find closed formulas to calculate them exactly, the simulators are extremely accurate, fast, and robust.

thanks - i have added links in question
